# remove extra space in song environment of musixguit

Tags: spacing, musixtex

I'm using `musixguit` package to write a songbook. And got some format issues within the `song` environment. Somehow there is an extra line at the end. See code and result here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{musixguit}

\begin{document}

\fbox{%
\noindent 
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth} %
\begin{song}%
    \chord{Em} Wenn im Glase \T\ \chord{B7} perlt der Sekt \T\ \\ 
    \chord{Am} unter roten \T\ \chord{Em} Ampeln \\
    \chord{Am} und die Weiber, \T\ \chord{Em} süß erschreckt, \T\ \\ 
    \chord{B7} auf dem Schoß uns \T\ trampeln, \\
    \chord{Em} küssen wir die \T\ \chord{B7} Prüderie \T\ \\ 
    \chord{Am} von den roten \T\ \chord{Em} Mündern, \\
    \chord{Am} Amnestie, \T\ \chord{Em} Amnestie \T\ \\
    \chord{B7} allen armen \T\ Sündern!
\end{song}%  
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%  
\begin{song}%
    \chord{Em} Wenn die Morgen- \T\ \chord{B7} dämmerung \T\ \\
    \chord{Am} hinter Fenster- \T\ \chord{Em} scheiben \\
    \chord{Am} und die Männer, \T\ \chord{Em} ohne Braut \T\ \\ 
    \chord{B7} beieinander \T\ bleiben, \\
    \chord{Em} schmieden wir im \T\ \chord{B7} Flüsterton \T\ \\
    \chord{Am} aus Gesprächen \T\ \chord{Em} Bomben. \\
    \chord{Am} Rebellion, \T\ \chord{Em} Rebellion \T\ \\
    \chord{B7} in den Kata- \T\ komben!
\end{song}%
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm pretty new on latex. Does anyone have a suggestion how to remove this extra line?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: You need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to show the umlauts correctly, but that is not the cause of your issue with the extra line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\end{song}` invokes `\end{spacing}` which apparently intentionally adds a `\baselineskip` space.

this just undoes that and fixes unrelated errors in the minipage widths so they fit on the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{musixguit}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\noindent
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-\fboxrule-\fboxsep}%
\begin{song}%
    \chord{Em} Wenn im Glase \T\ \chord{B7} perlt der Sekt \T\ \\ 
    \chord{Am} unter roten \T\ \chord{Em} Ampeln \\
    \chord{Am} und die Weiber, \T\ \chord{Em} süß erschreckt, \T\ \\ 
    \chord{B7} auf dem Schoß uns \T\ trampeln, \\
    \chord{Em} küssen wir die \T\ \chord{B7} Prüderie \T\ \\ 
    \chord{Am} von den roten \T\ \chord{Em} Mündern, \\
    \chord{Am} Amnestie, \T\ \chord{Em} Amnestie \T\ \\
    \chord{B7} allen armen \T\ Sündern!

\vskip-\baselineskip
\end{song}%  
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-\fboxrule-\fboxsep} % 
\begin{song}%
    \chord{Em} Wenn die Morgen- \T\ \chord{B7} dämmerung \T\ \\
    \chord{Am} hinter Fenster- \T\ \chord{Em} scheiben \\
    \chord{Am} und die Männer, \T\ \chord{Em} ohne Braut \T\ \\ 
    \chord{B7} beieinander \T\ bleiben, \\
    \chord{Em} schmieden wir im \T\ \chord{B7} Flüsterton \T\ \\
    \chord{Am} aus Gesprächen \T\ \chord{Em} Bomben. \\
    \chord{Am} Rebellion, \T\ \chord{Em} Rebellion \T\ \\
    \chord{B7} in den Kata- \T\ komben!

\vskip-\baselineskip
\end{song}%
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of `spacing` is dubious here; you could redefine the `song` environment by using just `\par\linespread{1.8}\selectfont` in the “begin” part and `\par` in the “end” part.

Perhaps it's better to define a new environment for the specific application:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{musixguit}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newsavebox{\twocolumnsongbox}
\newenvironment{boxedtwocolumnsong}[1][4em]
 {%
  \begin{center}
  \begin{lrbox}{\twocolumnsongbox}
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
  \linespread{1.8}\selectfont
  \setlength{\columnsep}{#1}%
  \begin{multicols}{2}
 }
 {%
  \end{multicols}\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \fbox{\usebox{\twocolumnsongbox}}%
  \end{center}
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedtwocolumnsong}
    \chord{Em} Wenn im Glase \T\ \chord{B7} perlt der Sekt \T\ \\ 
    \chord{Am} unter roten \T\ \chord{Em} Ampeln \\
    \chord{Am} und die Weiber, \T\ \chord{Em} süß erschreckt, \T\ \\ 
    \chord{B7} auf dem Schoß uns \T\ trampeln, \\
    \chord{Em} küssen wir die \T\ \chord{B7} Prüderie \T\ \\ 
    \chord{Am} von den roten \T\ \chord{Em} Mündern, \\
    \chord{Am} Amnestie, \T\ \chord{Em} Amnestie \T\ \\
    \chord{B7} allen armen \T\ Sündern!
    \chord{Em} Wenn die Morgen- \T\ \chord{B7} dämmerung \T\ \\
    \chord{Am} hinter Fenster- \T\ \chord{Em} scheiben \\
    \chord{Am} und die Männer, \T\ \chord{Em} ohne Braut \T\ \\ 
    \chord{B7} beieinander \T\ bleiben, \\
    \chord{Em} schmieden wir im \T\ \chord{B7} Flüsterton \T\ \\
    \chord{Am} aus Gesprächen \T\ \chord{Em} Bomben. \\
    \chord{Am} Rebellion, \T\ \chord{Em} Rebellion \T\ \\
    \chord{B7} in den Kata- \T\ komben!
\end{boxedtwocolumnsong}

\end{document}
```

[image]